# How to parse float value from firebase database in Unity3d C#

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

**How do I parse out numerical values vs string values in C# using firebase database? How do I get the value of `someNumber` below**

```
//in firebase database 
//thing["name"] = "Bob"
//thing["someNumber"] = 35.55


    reference.Child("whatever").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        Dictionary<string, object> thing = task.Result.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;
        string name = thing["name"] as string; //no problems here
        float number = thing["someNumber"] as float; //compile error
    });
```

Comment: What is the return type of of the indexer `thing["whatever"]`? Does it return some numerical type? A string representation a number? Something else?

Comment: That line would not generate an error if it really contained `35.55`, as you suggest. I'm suspecting you have not yet used the debugger to see what it really contains. Also, telling us the actual type might be helpful too.

Comment: @JonathanWood That line will generate a compile time error to begin with. `as` can't be used with value types. He should be, if anything, casting: `float number = (float)thing["someNumber"];`

Answer (score 2):

The operator `as` can not be used with value types; you will get a compile time error.

If you are sure that `thing["whatever"]` will always return a valid `float` or a type that has a user conversion (explicit or implicit operator) to `float` then simply perform a cast:

```
float number = (float)thing["someNumber"];
```

If whatever `thing["someNumber"]` is not castable to a `float` then you will get a runtime error. It's your call if you need a safety net or not for this plausible scenario.